# Effect of Drain-source voltage on NMOS operation

Tags: cmos, nmos

I have been trying to understand the NMOS operation through various online tutorials but I am getting stuck in understanding the effect of increasing drain voltage on the flow of current and the channel length. I did understand that at similar drain and source potential current does not flow and only after applying positive potential to drain, current starts flowing from source to drain. Can anybody explain me the characteristics when drain source voltage is gradually increased and specially its relation with the threshold voltage?

Comment: Which threshold voltage do you refer to?

Comment: @Andy A certain level of voltage applied to the gate-source beyond which current starts flowing.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply a voltage to the gate of an NMOS FET that is greater than the threshold voltage \$V_{t}\$, a channel of electrons is formed under the gate. That channel connects the drain and source so that when you apply a voltage \$ V_{ds}\$, a current flows from between these terminals. In this mode, the MOSFET behaves almost like a resistor, so the current flow depends (although not linearly) on \$V_{ds}\$, but the current will also increase with the gate-source voltage \$V_{gs}\$ because increasing this makes the channel deeper, reducing its resistance. That explains the first part of the curve (active or triode).

However, the electric field near the drain depends not just on \$V_{gs}\$ but also on \$V_{ds}\$. Once \$V_{ds} = V_{gs} - V_{t}\$ (called \$V_{ds,sat}\$) the electric field is cancelled near drain and the channel becomes shorter, no longer reaching the drain, leaving a depletion region between the end of the channel and the drain. Any further increase in \$V_{ds}\$ is dropped across this depletion region so the voltage across the channel stays constant at \$V_{ds,sat}\$ and the current flow is also constant. That is the second region of the curve (saturation).

The explanation of the saturation region above would suggest that FET current is constant with \$V_{ds}\$ in the saturation region. Obviously, from the current-voltage curves we can see that this is not the case, and actually the current slowly rises. This is due to an effect called channel length modulation. As \$V_{ds}\$ continues to increase, it cancels the inverted channel even further from the drain, leading to the channel shortening. This reduces the channel resistance (resistance is proportional to length) leading to higher current flow.

There are obviously a lot of second order effects not covered here, but those are the basics!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see the characteristic curves in any MOSFET datasheet.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd19501kcs.pdf

You can also see the empirically derived equations if you Google a bit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET

Finally, you can use any of the free SPICE simulators to set up a quick simulation and run the curves yourself.

http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/

Comment: @John D- Thanks for the help. I am actually looking for an explanation of the curve. More specifically, why increase in drain voltage beyond a certain point saturates the current flow and results in a pinch off?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the MOSFET is in triode region (i.e *Vgs* > *Vth* and *Vds* < *Vgs*-*Vth*), with  the increase in drain voltage *Vds* with respect to source terminal, drain current *Id* increases. In this case the relation between the *Vds* and *Ids* is linear. Hence it can be said that, MOSFET's working in triode mode is similar to that of resistor but not exactly.

When Vds increases and MOSFET moves to saturation mode (i.e *Vds* >= *Vgs*-*Vth*), the drain current *Ids* ideally becomes constant and has no effect on it due to increase in drain voltage *Vds*. This is due **Channel Length Modulation** effect. According to this effect, *Vds* not only increases the kinetic energy of electrons moving from drain to source (and making up the drain current) but also shortens the length of the inverted channel region from drain side which was required for *Ids* to flow. Hence both the effect cancelled each other and *Ids* remains same.

Practically, there occurs a small increase in *Ids* with respect to increase in *Vds*, owing to the fact that the resistance of inversion layers decreases with the shortening of the length of the inverted channel.